# BigQuery table: loading .7z file form cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a compressed file from my GCS bucket into BigQuery.
In the new UI it is not clear how should I specify to uncompress the file.

I get an error specifying as if the `gs://bucket/folder/file.7z` is a `.csv` file.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, .7z files are not supported by Bigquery, only [gzip](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data) files and the decompression process is made automatically, after selecting the [data format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#supported_data_formats) and creating the table.

If you consider that BigQuery should accept 7z files too, you could fill a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) so the BigQuery engineers have it in mind for further releases.

Comment: I do not see 7z compressed files in the big data world (AWS, Azure, Alibaba, Google). There is already a supported set, (IMHO) I doubt that 7z will be added. The key question that I don't know about 7z: "is 7z streamable and splittable?".